# What does a Core Animation rendering error 506 mean?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-animation

I've got this error on my device console log but I'm unable to find anything about it. I don't know what is the cause of this error, where to find any remarks or anything:

```
Tue Dec 14 09:46:05 unknown com.apple.SpringBoard[46] <Notice>: CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
Tue Dec 14 09:46:05 unknown com.apple.SpringBoard[46] <Notice>: CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
Tue Dec 14 09:46:05 unknown com.apple.SpringBoard[46] <Notice>: CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
```

This error happens randomly (and it's very rare) in my iPad application, basicly it makes a whole screen go black (for exception of buttons with images and some labels). When I exit the application I've got a blank spots (covered with black) on my virtual keyboard (so somehow it gets from application to iOS).

Here is a video of this in action: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2YilAVXqAo

What can cause this and how can I avoid this error?

Comment: smells like an out of memory error - are there any memory warning callbacks called before this happens?

Comment: You need to get your iPad checked and possibly replaced. It is most probably the faulty hardware causing the issue.

Comment: First thing I would do to verify if its faulty hardware is to test it on another iPad, may be iPad 2.Rendering Error usually are caused by GPU unable to accept and show UI.Also what are you trying to load onto the screen.It might be that the frame buffer is getting overloaded

Comment: Agreeing with the above comments here; can you share a generalized version of the source for what you are trying to render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was pointed out it was an out of memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that an [OpenGL rendering error](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GL_Error_Codes)?
If so that would be GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION. If you're not making any OpenGL calls yourself, you should file a bug with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.
I got the same error message in Xcode while working on a Cordova based project. I don't use webGL in my project, only JS/HTML/CSS embeded in a webview thanks to Cordova.

Each time the error was returned I could also see a quick disparition of some elements (HTML div tag) on my device screen.

For me the problem was due to a simple CSS transform scaleX rendering in a RequestAnimationFrame function. I was calculating a percentage to increase a progress bar. In the RequestAnimationFrame function, I was setting (with jQuery) a new CSS style on the progress bar with the transform property. Eg:

```
function step(timestamp) {
    var percent = getPercentSpent();
    $('#bar').css({'transform':'scaleX('+percent+')'});// Source of problem in my case
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

Removing this CSS transform from the project also removed the error. I got the error message on both iPhone 4S IOS9 and iPhone5c iOS10 before removing this line.

Hope this could help.